# Render ssrs report in mvc(Razor) application without using nuget package

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting-services

I have a rdl report and I want to display it on the web page of my application without using Nuget Package so I can't use ReportViewer for MVC. Please let me know if there is any other way to do this.

Comment: You can always use ASPX page to render `ReportViewer` control. Make sure that it inherits `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage` to be recognizable as view by MVC controller (and you can put webforms ReportViewer tag there).

Comment: Hi. I tried to run report from aspx page using ReportViewer on localhost but I am getiing error: attempt to connect to report server failed. My report server is hosted on localhost url and mvc application is also hosted on localhost:port. Could you provide any help?

Comment: You can create ASPX view page inheriting `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage`, then add `ReportViewer` control on it and put some code in `Page_Load` method (no need to use `.aspx.cs` file, just use `<script runat="server">` there). Then you can pass necessary data from controller to that view page.

Comment: I have created rdl report using report builder and have uploaded the same on reporting url and I have given reportserverurl and reportpath in the ReportViewer tag with <scriptManager runat = "server"> and In my controller action I have redirected to this aspx page.